# How to display Text in new line in CoDesys visualization

Tags: codesys

In CoDeSys visualization, how to display Text in newline.

I have a csv file which reads by CoDeSys and display the csv column text in CoDesys rectangle text block.

In csv file I tried giving $N, \n\r,\n,  no chance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From:
http://infosys.beckhoff.de/english.php?content=../content/1033/TcPlcControl/HTML/TcPlcVisu_edit_configElement.htm&id=
one learns:
"With the key combination Crtl+Enter you can insert line breaks, with Crtl+Tab, tab stops."

So, press Crtl+Enter to start a new line and check how CoDeSys separates lines. Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for your answer, this link helped us to solve answer

Answer (score 3):

To define a new line you have to type '$N'. Example: 'Hello$NWorld'

I hope it works!